# How to remove the white background of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I want to remove the default white background of UITableViewCell like I want the background of the cell being transparent so that it shows the actual background of the window.

Answer (score 7):

I Got it.

```
UIView *backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = backView;
```